# Rendering Persian (Farsi) words in PIL for Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts, python-imaging-library, persian

I am trying to make images based on Persian (Farsi) text.
I am using PIL for Python3. Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
text = "خطاب"
image = Image.new("RGBA", (100,100), (255,255,255))
font = ImageFont.truetype("FreeFarsiMono.ttf", 60, encoding='unic')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.text((0,0), text, (0,0,0), font=font)
image.save("Test.png")
image.show()
```

However when I run the code I get some rectangular boxes with question mark in them, instead of the image of the text!
I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Try making `text` a `unicode`: `text = u"خطاب"`.

Comment: I'm guessing here but do you need to encode the text into UTF-8 before passing to PIL?  Unfortunately the documentation doesn't seem to say.

Comment: @unutbu That helped a little, now the question marks are gone, but I have 3 disjoint letters. The above Farsi word has 3 connected and on disconnected lette.

Comment: @neil how can I do that? I thought what I have as text is already UTF-8, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @TJ1 You would use `text.encode()` - the default encoding is utf-8.  Python3 strings are an internal representation of unicode that needs encoded to one of many encodings before outputting.  However, I have just tested it and PIL gives an error when you send the encoded version to it.  I'm afraid that's as far as my guessing went and I was wrong.

Comment: @TJ1: I realize Farsi and Arabic are not the same, but is [this](http://mpcabd.igeex.biz/python-arabic-text-reshaper/) helpful?

Comment: I've now tried doing exactly what you have - including installing the FreeFarsi font and it works fine.  What system are you working on and what version of python and PIL are you using?  I tested it on Windows 7 with Python 3.3.1 and Pillow 2.1.0.

Comment: I also found that the text was backwards.  I think the module @unutbu links to may be of use for this but I used the brute force `text[::-1]`.

Comment: You may try another fonts too. Used font possibly not Unicode support.

Answer (score 1):

Many problems can occur for Persian(Farsi) or Arabic fonts, including:

1. Wrong direction (right to left problem)
2. Shape problem (characters are in the isolated form, which means that every character is rendered regardless of its surroundings). For example (س‌ل‌ا‌م  and سلام )
3. Encoding problem (Rectangular boxes)

For the 1st problem we have to use the *Unicode bidirectional algorithm*, which is implemented in [python-bidi](https://github.com/MeirKriheli/python-bidi).
For the 2nd problem [arabic_reshaper](https://github.com/mpcabd/python-arabic-reshaper) works well, even with Persian characters such as ژ , پ, گ and چ.
The last one is the simplest, just change the encoding to utf8.

```
# install: pip install arabic-reshaper
import arabic_reshaper

# install: pip install python-bidi
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

text_to_be_reshaped = 'کلاس ویژن'
reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text_to_be_reshaped) # seperated chars problem
bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text) #direction problem


text = bidi_text.encode().decode('utf-8') #encoding problem (rectangular boxes!)

image = Image.new("RGBA", (200,100), (255,255,255))
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial", 45, encoding='unic')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.text((0,0), text, (0,0,0), font=font)
image.save("Test.png")
image.show()
```

The output:

[image: Correct Persian text in python]

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set the coding of the source:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Then you have to decode your text:

```
text = text.decode('utf-8')
```

Your final code should be sth like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

text = "ﻡﻼﺳ"
text = text.decode('utf-8')
image = Image.new("RGBA", (100,100), (255,255,255))
font = ImageFont.truetype("yekan.ttf", 45, encoding='unic')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.text((0,0), text, (0,0,0), font=font)
image.save("Test.png")
image.show()
```

*Note* If you had your letters separated, you'd convert them; e.g. you can use [awebfont](http://awebfont.ir/convert/) to solve that problem.

Output:

[image: Test.png]